# Fastload to temporal table

Tags: teradata

Had a cvs file containing 3 fields

```
1,cat,2012-06-16,2013-06-16 
1,cat,2013-06-16,
```

I am trying to load that to temporal table having valid_dt PERIOD(DATE) using fastload script

```
nonsequenced validtime    
INSERT INTO financial.test1 (id,name,valid_dt) values
(:id,:name,period( cast(:start_dt as date FORMAT 'YYYY-MM-DD'),cast(:end_dt as date FORMAT  'YYYY-MM-DD'))
);
```

Error I got is RDBMS error 3618: Expression not allowed in Fast Load
              Insert, column INTERNALPERIODDATETYPE.

could not find any in manuals, they only said it will be possible with fastload.

Thankyou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FastLoad doesn't allow ANSI style CAST, must be old Teradata style instead:

```
:start_dt (date, FORMAT 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

But there's no old-style PERIOD cast and FastLoad also doesn't allow any kind of expression and PERIOD(...) **is** an expression.

So you can only load data which can be automatically converted to a PEROD like:

```
1;cat;(2012-06-16, 2013-06-16) 
1;cat;(2013-06-16, 9999-12-31)
```

Including the parens, the blank after the comma and a different delimiter...

I would suggest simply loading the data as DATEs (or CHARs) into a staging table using FastLoad or MultiLoad, followed by a

```
nonsequenced validtime    
INSERT INTO financial.test1 (id,name,valid_dt) values
select id, name, period(start_dt,COALESCE(end_dt, date '9999-12-31'))
from stagingtable
```